# dynamically adding/removing rows & controls in grid in silverlight

Tags: silverlight

I am trying to create a rule screen where user can specify different rules, save them & later on apply on data. User can also group the rules for AND OR condition. My query is if this is the right way to do it & when user clicks on remove that row should be removed, I am not sure how to do that?

Following is my XAML :

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" Width="600" Height="200" ShowGridLines="True">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions><RowDefinition Height="30" /></Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions><ColumnDefinition Width="135"/><ColumnDefinition Width="25"/><ColumnDefinition Width="135"/><ColumnDefinition Width="135"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="135"/><ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <telerik:RadComboBox Name="Header" Grid.Row="0" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Content="And" IsSelected="True"></telerik:RadComboBoxItem>
            <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Content="Or"></telerik:RadComboBoxItem>
        </telerik:RadComboBox>
    <telerik:RadButton Content="+" Height="31" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="106,0,0,0" Name="btnAdd" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="26" Click="btnAdd_Click" />
</Grid>
```

And code behind is:

```
   private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var row = new RowDefinition();

        row.Height = new GridLength(30);
        LayoutRoot.RowDefinitions.Add(row);

        var columnCombo = new Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadComboBox() { Width = 100, Height = 30, HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left };
        columnCombo.Items.Add("Column1");
        columnCombo.Items.Add("Column2");
        columnCombo.Items.Add("Column3");

        var operatorCombo = new Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadComboBox() { Width = 100, Height = 30, HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left};
        operatorCombo.Items.Add("contains");
        operatorCombo.Items.Add("startsWith");
        operatorCombo.Items.Add("endsWith");

        var btnRemove = new Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadButton() { Width = 20, Height = 30, Content = "X" };
        btnRemove.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(btnRemove_Click);

        var btnGroup = new Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadButton() { Content = "Group", Width = 50, Height = 30 };
        btnGroup.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        btnGroup.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(btnGroup_Click);

        var calendar = new Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadDatePicker();

        LayoutRoot.Children.Add(btnRemove);
        LayoutRoot.Children.Add(btnGroup);
        LayoutRoot.Children.Add(columnCombo);
        LayoutRoot.Children.Add(operatorCombo);
        LayoutRoot.Children.Add(calendar);

        int newrow = LayoutRoot.RowDefinitions.Count-1;

        Grid.SetRow(btnRemove, newrow);
        Grid.SetColumn(btnRemove, 1);
        Grid.SetRow(columnCombo, newrow);
        Grid.SetColumn(columnCombo, 2);
        Grid.SetRow(operatorCombo, newrow);
        Grid.SetColumn(operatorCombo, 3);
        Grid.SetRow(calendar, newrow);
        Grid.SetColumn(calendar, 4);
        Grid.SetRow(btnGroup, newrow);
        Grid.SetColumn(btnGroup, 5);

    }

    public void btnGroup_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void btnRemove_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        //TODO: Here I want to find out from which Gridrow user has clicked & remove that grid row & controls inside it.
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `Tag` property of each button to get the row you want to delete.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.tag(v=vs.95).aspx